# How to split model declaration in files with Peewee

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

I would like to split my code that define the models in my database in differents Python files, to have my project more structured.

Sadly, I end up with an inclusion loop, and an error show up cause some stuff is not initialized when it should be.

I have done something like this for now (simplified) :

```py
# In file file_database.py

import peewee as pw

from tables import Table1, Table2, Table3

DATABASE_PATH = ...
MY_DB = pw.SqliteDatabase(DATABASE_PATH)

def make_tables():
    """Make the tables in the database if they don't already exist."""
    MY_DB.create_tables([Table1, Table2, Table3]) # Problem happens here

# Create the database file if it doesn't already exist
if not DATABASE_PATH.exists():
    LOGGER.info("The database doesn't exists. Creating it...")
    make_tables()

# In file tables.py

import peewee as pw

from file_database import MY_DB

class BaseModel(pw.Model):
    class Meta:
        database = MY_DB

class Table1(BaseModel):
    name = ...

class Table2(BaseModel):
    name = ...

class Table3(BaseModel):
    name = ...
```

And I have a exception like :
`ImportError: cannot import name 'Table1'`
which seems to be logic as the function `makeTables` needs to import the tables from `tables.py` first.
But this one needs the database from `file_database.py`.

So I'm stuck here.
I also tried to place the `from tables import Table1, Table2, Table3` inside the `makeTables` function to try to do some kind of lazy loading, but without success.

Is there an helping hand out there ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make a third module which brings in both and orchestrates the import order.

The general process is described in detail here:

http://charlesleifer.com/blog/structuring-flask-apps-a-how-to-for-those-coming-from-django/

Answer (score 1):

Nice tutorial, havn't understood it all, but here's a code that works :

In `database/__init__.py`

```py
import database.tables
from database import file_database

file_database.initialization()
```

In `database/tables.py`

```py
import peewee as pw

MY_DB = pw.SqliteDatabase(None) # Create a blank database here

class BaseModel(pw.Model):
    class Meta:
        database = MY_DB

class Table1(BaseModel):
    name = ...

class Table2(BaseModel):
    name = ...

class Table3(BaseModel):
    name = ...
```

In `database/file_database.py`

```py
import peewee as pw

from database.tables import MY_DB, Table1, Table2, Table3

DATABASE_PATH = ...

def make_tables():
    """Make the tables in the database"""
    MY_DB.create_tables([Table1, Table2, Table3])

def initialization():
    MY_DB.init(DATABASE_PATH) # Actually init the database

    # Create the database file if it doesn't already exist
    if not DATABASE_PATH.exists():
        LOGGER.info("The database doesn't exists. Creating it...")
        make_tables()
```

Comment: the part of peewee apps that need to be modularized into different files is Table1, Table2, Table3